# Pandas index doesn't return row names in my example

Tags: python, pandas

It seems `df.index` is actually executing `df.RangeIndex`

For example:

```
ok = pd.DataFrame({"game":["red","blue","green"], "player":["Tom","Brad","Dan"], "score":[100,300,250]})
ok.set_index(["game"])
ok.index
```

I can confirm the row names are the values of `game`, however the `df.index` produces this instead:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

Looking at `help(ok.index)` seems to think it is indeed a `RangeIndex` command. So how do you get row values?

Comment: `set_index` by default is **not** inplace operation. Try `ok.set_index(["game"], inplace=True)`

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
ok = pd.DataFrame({"game":["red","blue","green"], "player":["Tom","Brad","Dan"], "score":[100,300,250]})
ok2 = ok.set_index(["game"])
ok2.index #which gives Index(['red', 'blue', 'green'], dtype='object', name='game')
```

and if you want to mutate the original DataFrame, then you should pass `inplace=True` in `set_index` method

```
ok.set_index(["game"], inplace=True)
```

like above one would mutate the DataFrame and set the index as desired